# Getting two firebase database children at the same time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my ProfilePage.class and which is going to display the profile of the user but I have a problem because I have two different types of users. One of them is a normal user and the other businessUser. How do I call both children of the database and display certain information in xml layout depending of the type of user so far I have this below but it doesn't work properly.

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_page_both);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");
    mDatabaseBuisness = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("businessAcc");

     mNormalUserProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.normalUserProfilePic);
     mNormalUserEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.normalUserEmail);
     mNormalUserProfile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.normalUserProfile);
     mBusinessUserPostcode = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.businessPostcode);



   String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();



    mDatabase.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



                String profile_username = (String) dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue();
                String profile_image = (String) dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue();
                String profile_uid = (String) dataSnapshot.child("uid").getValue();
                String profile_email = (String) dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue();


                mNormalUserEmail.setText(profile_email);
                mNormalUserProfile.setText(profile_username);

                Picasso.with(ProfilePageNormalUser.this).load(profile_image).into(mNormalUserProfilePic);



            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });

    mDatabaseBuisness.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



            String profile_username = (String) dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue();
            String profile_image = (String) dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue();
            String profile_uid = (String) dataSnapshot.child("uid").getValue();
            String profile_email = (String) dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue();
            String profile_postcode = (String) dataSnapshot.child("postCode").getValue();


            mNormalUserEmail.setText(profile_email);
            mNormalUserProfile.setText(profile_username);
            mBusinessUserPostcode.setText(profile_postcode);

            Picasso.with(ProfilePageNormalUser.this).load(profile_image).into(mNormalUserProfilePic);



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
```

Here is the database structure:

[image]

Comment: I might be able to answer this, but first let me ask. Is it possible for one uid to have value inside both `user` and `businessAcc`?

Comment: Wait, it looks like your code will work if the answer of my previous question is no. So, what exactly you want to ask?

Comment: I merged to single database. To save the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-initiating the Firebase Reference that is the issue.To Solve your problem.

First take the root reference.

```
DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Then create two separate reference from the root reference.

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = mRootRef.child("users");
DatabaseReference buisnessAccRef = mRootRef.child("businessAcc");
```

Now you can do your stuff using these references.

Comment: Still doesn't work it doesn't display one profile but displays the other.

Comment: can you share your database structure ?

Comment: I edited and added it. Basically I want if the user ID is a business acc user to display different than the normal user.

Comment: DatabaseReference usersRef = mRootRef.child("user");   use user instead of users . and also check do you have user with same uid on both reference ?. i can't spot any on the image you shared.(user and businessAcc) .

Comment: I will just put them in one database

Comment: I have been trying to fix it for so long I think I need an If statement or something to say that if its user do this if its business do this.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,I know what do you exactly mean
you can use the snapMap as follow :

```
Map<String,String>snapMap = mapOf("from","","to","","imageUrl","","ImageName","");

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
                     .child(keys.get(position)).child("snaps").push().setValue(snapMap);

// push is for generate a random id 
// you can put your value insted of empty string
```